# Why does rust libc use repr(packed) for struct?

Tags: rust

Rust libc use `repr(packed)` as shown [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/blob/4af234205f440be38d9036a5bdbcfeed55fb2ced/src/unix/linux_like/mod.rs#L214) for struct which will be then passed to system libc. For example, [utsname](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/blob/4af234205f440be38d9036a5bdbcfeed55fb2ced/src/unix/linux_like/mod.rs#L234) is `repr(packed)` and then used in [fn uname](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/blob/4af234205f440be38d9036a5bdbcfeed55fb2ced/src/unix/linux_like/mod.rs#L1689)
As per the doc mentioned [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html#reprpacked),

```
repr(packed) forces Rust to strip any padding, and only align the type to a byte. This may improve the memory footprint, but will likely have other negative side-effects.

In particular, most architectures strongly prefer values to be aligned. This may mean the unaligned loads are penalized (x86),
```

Then why does rust libc use `repr(packed)` and not `repr(C)` for passing struct to system libc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then why does rust libc use `repr(packed)` and not `repr(C)` for passing struct to system libc?

One obvious reason is that the equivalent structures are specified as packed on the C side as well. (Many C compilers support "packed" as a [non-standard](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/253503/why-are-packed-structures-not-part-of-the-c-language) extension with the same meaning as in Rust.) The definition of `epoll_event` on Linux confirms this:

```
#ifdef __x86_64__
#define EPOLL_PACKED __attribute__((packed))
#else
#define EPOLL_PACKED
#endif

struct epoll_event {
        __u32 events;
        __u64 data;
} EPOLL_PACKED;
```

The same should apply to the other examples.